# Java arraylist. I need to pass random numbers to an array list and pass them to another class to check those numbers against another set of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am confused with passing ARRAYLIST values from one class to another.
I used the ARRAY in these classes before. I am changed those with ARRAYLISTS.

I have 2 classes. this class has an ARRAYLIST called "locationcells". This programs get 3 random digits from another class and get uses inputs and check if their inputs match the 3 digits. it's more like a guessing game.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class SimpleDotCom {

    private ArrayList<String> locationcells;

    public void setLocationcells(ArrayList<String> Locs)
    {
        locationcells = Locs;       
    }

    public String CheckYourself(String StringGuess)
    {

            String result = " Miss";
            int index = locationcells.indexOf(StringGuess);

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                    locationcells.remove(index);

                    if (locationcells.isEmpty())
                    {
                        result = "Kill";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Hit";
                    }

            }

        return result;      

    }
}
```

this looks right.
Now the class with the main method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class SimpleDotComGame {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numOfGuesses = 0;
        GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();

        SimpleDotCom theDotCom = new SimpleDotCom();

        /*
        this is the part I don't understand. I used to have the int array and generated random numbers and it worked well.


        int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

        ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();

        */

        theDotCom.setLocationcells(locations);

        boolean isAlive = true;

        while (isAlive == true)
        {
            String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter a number");
            String result = theDotCom.CheckYourself(guess);
            numOfGuesses++;

            if (result.equals("Kill"))
            {
                isAlive = false;
                System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + "guesses");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

If you see the comments section above. That's the part I am getting confused. I used to have an array there. INT array. So I was able to pass the INT random numbers to the "simpledotcom" class. Now it is an arraylist with string type, I am not sure how to move forward.

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: You don't 'pass' something to a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always transform the random `int` to a string by using `Integer.toString()` before inserting into your array list.

You can convert the `String` back to `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`

E.g.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    locations.add(Integer.toString((int)(Math.random() * 5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int numericGuess = Integer.parseInt(helper.getUserInput("Enter a number"));
```

Also you can use a list of Integers too:

```
ArrayList<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(//condition){
 int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
 locations.add(randomNum)
}
```

this way you can perform
`locations.indexOf(numericGuess)` or `locations.contains(numericGuess)`

**OR**

Conversely  you can do,

```
String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter a number");

ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
while(//condition){
 int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
 locations.add(String.valueOf(randomNum))
}
```

and check by 
`locations.indexOf(guess)` or `locations.contains(guess)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well: add 3 Strings to the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    { locations.add(String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 5))); }
```

Anyway, you might refactor a little as well, starting with the extracting the above lines from the main method.

Another way might be to store your integer in a list, and convert the guesses to integers. Looks more logic to me anyway. In that case, you'll have an ArrayList. To convert a string to an integer:

```
int guessNumber = Integer.parseInt(guess);
```

or

```
Integer guessNumber = Integer.valueOf(guess);
```

Both will throw a NumberFormatException if 'guess' does not contain a parseble integer (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) )

Why are you not using arrays like (apparently) you did before, by the way?